# How to add dynamically dropdown for each item I get from a list?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, custom, toolpart

I am working on a custom editor part (WebParts.EditorPart) where I am reading a list, this list provides me with the links to different websites which are attached to a checkbox, so the user can select their favorite links, this is working well so far and my WebPart displays the 12 selected links properly.

The new requirement is to have for each list item (or each checkbox) a dropdownlist besides and prefilled with values from 1 to 12, so the users can select also the order of appearance in the WebPart (they can just select 12 links), something similar to the View Settings Option in a normal list in SharePoint, where the user selects which fields to be displayed and the order.

Anyone have an idea?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why 1 to 12?  Couldn't there theoretically be more than 12 links in this List?

Comment: I know it could be more than 12, but the requirements are just to fullfil the ddls with values from 1 to 12

Comment: Have you tried using InfoPath to develop your form?  There are a lot more options with that tool for forms creation.

Comment: it is not a form, maybe I was not clear, but I wrote that I am working on a custom editor part (or tool part).

Comment: I think maybe you should be more clear and add more details about what you are trying to accomplish.  You mean a web part?  Are you trying to modify the configuration menu for the web part, or the web part itself?

Comment: Hmmm... what I am trying to accomplish? well, I think that has been writting since the beginning, also, I'm not expert in SharePoint+Visual Studio, but my understanding tells me that just Web Parts have an "Editor part" (or toolpanel) which is as you call it "the configuration menu" of the we part, which is a Custom Web Part, so I am creating a Custom Web Part with a Custom Editor Part

Answer (score 1):

Sinuhe,

MSDN provides a pretty reasonable guide for what it is you are trying to do.  Please check out "[Creating a Custom Web Part Editor in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228018%28v=office.14%29.aspx)" and see if that offers you any help.  I can't give you the specific answer you are looking for but this should at least point you in the right direction.  Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way to avoid using Visual Studio in this scenario so you will need to try to familiarize yourself with it.